# Verb of probability

Tags: verbs

I need to express my idea that I need to generate probabilistic data from raw data. Is there a verb that can express this meaning ? For example, computing probabilities for sensor data => "probabilize" sensor data.

Edit: Peter Shor is correct. What I mean is "To cause to be probable or to seem probable."

Edit2: Since there are some misunderstandings, I think I should provide more context. I have collected raw data from various sensors. However, my application requires probabilistic data. Therefore, I need a way to "probabilize" the raw data i.e., generate probabilistic data from the raw data.

Comment: In information theory, where turning things into probabilities is used in soft decoding, it would be called something like *"computing likelihoods of sensor data"* or *"computing the likelihood function for sensor data"*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use also the verbs :  **measure** or **gauge** probabilities for sensor data.

Comment: ... or **calculate** probabilities. It's not clear which of these verbs corresponds to what the OP wants.

Comment: I think OP was looking for a single word, like the suggested 'probabilize'. One of the many suggested will do I think.

Comment: Measure,gauge or calculate can not express the meaning I want. It seems that there is no single verb that can do beside the verb probabilize, which is not very common.

Comment: Actually 'probabilize' does not mean to measure the probabilities for something. Just check carefully the meaning you want to convey.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase “computing probabilities for sensor data” ordinarily would be understood as referring to *[statistically testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_test)* a dataset, or *[statistically analyzing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_test)* a dataset.

If instead of statistically testing or analyzing a set of data you mean probabilistically creating a new set of data, you would refer to making a *[probabilistic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_model)*, a  *statistical model*, or a *[stochastic model](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stochastic)*.  Such a model formalizes one's assumptions about some data's *[probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution)*.  For example, many quantities have values that closely correspond to a *[normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)*, while others may correspond to a *[binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)* or *[geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)*.  Queuing inter-arrival times typically are modeled via a *[Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)*.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probabilize

According to merriam-webster, the word "probabilize" has been invented. That doesn't mean it's proper English though.

Comment: [Probabilize](https://www.wordnik.com/words/probabilize) does not mean what the OP wants. It means *"To cause to be probable or to seem probable."*

Comment: Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.